# Forwarding Port 22 for SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward port 22 so I can SSH into my PC from a different network but it doesn't seem to be working. I get the classic "Connection refused" error. I can do ssh mihkel@my_public_ip from the network that the PC is on but it doesn't work on any other network. I've made sure port 22 is allowed in the Windows Firewall and that the IP is correct.. Here is my port forwarding config:[image]

I have a Inteno DG400 router and the PC is connected on via Wi-Fi. I was told to keep Source Port(s) empty but I cannot save the config if it is empty.

Update: I've tried to set firewall rule to allow access to port 22, still I have the same problem. Nothing has changed. Here are the settings for the firewall rules:[image]

Comment: So your ISP is probably blocking incoming connections to port 22. Try other ports. You only need to change the “Source Port”.

Comment: This router's "Source Port" is slightly mislabeled; it really means the destination port of the original packet from the source zone. So while a _real_ source port field would indeed be kept empty, that doesn't apply here and setting it to some value is correct.

Comment: So, uh, just to be sure: You see your public IP address on the router’s status page, right? Is it the same IP you see when using a web service for checking your public IP?

Comment: @DanielB yes and yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings seem correct, and Source Port should certainly not be empty when
doing port-forwarding (or there is nothing to forward).

So it seems that port 22 is being blocked. It works when you self-loop from your
computer to your computer through the router, but does not work from the
real Internet.

To find out why it is blocked, check first the router if this port is not allowed.
The [manual](https://www.intenogroup.com/products/legacy/dg400/)
for your router is basically empty, so you will have to find it out the hard way
from the router's login page.
Ports are often called "services" and this is normally found in the Firewall
section of the settings.

Once you are sure that the port should not be blocked on your side, this leaves
your ISP.

Try a service such as
[GRC | ShieldsUP!](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2),
option Common Ports, to see which ports are open, and check port 22.

If port 22 is blocked, this means that either your router is still blocking it,
or that the ISP does.
If any other port is open, you might use it as the Source port instead of port 22.

If none of the above worked, contacting your ISP Support might help.

Note: The router might have a DMZ setting to direct everything to your computer.
Avoid it, as it is too dangerous.

Comment: None of the ports are open in the "Common Ports" section of ShieldsUP!, all of them are listed as: "Stealth: There is NO EVIDENCE WHATSOEVER that a port (or even any computer) exists at this IP address!". Does this mean they are closed?

Comment: It means that there is no acknowledgement when addressing these ports. The likely explanation is that the router's firewall doesn't acknowledge the requests, since an ISP is unlikely to close all of them.

Comment: Hmm, what can I do about this? Does it have anything to do with firewall rules?

Comment: It has everything to do with firewall rules. I cannot find a manual for your router, but search for services to authorize. The service name might even be "SSH". Otherwise, add a firewall rule to let port 22 through from any IP address.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I have to be heading to bed now, but I'll pick up tomorrow with the firewall rules. I appreciate the help so far.

Comment: I've edited the original to include info on my firewall rule settings. Still not working.

Comment: Try to allow both the TCP and UDP protocols on port 22.

Comment: Done, not working still. The firewall rule also had a "FORWARD" option, that one didn't work either. canyouseeme.org can't find anything on the port either.

Comment: Very very strange. Did you try to contact Support of the ISP?

Comment: Haven’t yet but it seems like I’ll have to. Is there anything else I can try though? Also I never restarted the router after applying settings, could that be important?

Comment: Lacking a good manual for the router, it seems that what you are now doing should work, but doesn't. I think it#s time to call the ISP, especially if that router came from them.

Comment: I've called the ISP, they weren't very helpful at all saying they only block some specific ports (25, 80, 133) for security reasons and that everything is fine on their side. When I asked them how I can open a port on my router they just said a service needs to be running on it. I don't want to change ISPs over this thing.

Comment: They should give you exact instructions about what needs to be done. In many cases Support can intervene over the Internet (although that doorway should be closed afterward). I don't know anything about your situation, but I would have insisted on better information and support.